# Adjectives that modify more than one noun

Tags: gramática, adjetivos

Where do you place an adjective (or noun adjunct in the following example) in Spanish if it is understood in the English to modify more than one noun in the sentence? For example:

> "Members of the classis committees, commissions, or boards shall be members of a church."

In the English version, the word "classis" applies to all three nouns--it means "classis committees," "classis commissions," and "classis boards."

Is the meaning intact if the adjective is placed at the end of the list of three nouns, e.g.

> "Miembros de los comités, comisiones, y juntas del clasis deberán ser miembros de una iglesia."

Or would it be understood in that sentence to be referring only to "juntas"?

Comment: A common problem with that kind of sentences in Spanish is how to make clear that you are modifying only one noun. The usual way out is to alter the order: "Los miembros de las juntas del classis, comités y comisiones ..."

Comment: Where's the adjective in your question? Whatever "classis" means, it appears to be a noun which is used to form a compound noun phrase.

Comment: @Peter Taylor "Classis" functions as a noun adjunct (you could also call it a compound noun phrase if you prefer). It functions in a similar manner as an adjective would in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your translation is almost correct. This works more or less as in English, with the obvious difference that adjective goes at the end, not at the beginning.

I write *almost* because you made two small mistakes unrelated with what you ask here. Correction:

> Los miembros de los comités, comisiones o juntas del classis deberán
>   ser miembros de una iglesia.

Answer (score 1):

Since it refers to religious matters, I'm understanding that *classis* is translated as *claustro* which refers to a person in a higher religious position amoung church, therefore, the correct translation would be

> Miembros de los comités, comisiones, y juntas del claustro deberán ser miembros de una iglesia.

Comment: "Claustro" would not be an accurate translation. The word "classis" refers not to a person, but to a higher assembly (made up of a group of churches, usually within a particular geographic area) in a presbyterian church order. I don't believe there is a direct translation for the word in Spanish; my denomination uses the English word spelled according to Spanish rules--"clasis" (I just realized I spelled it incorrectly in my original post).